# Drop lines in MSChart

Tags: c#, mschart

I am using MSChart in my C# program to create line graphs, and am unable to find any options to create "drop lines" i.e. lines dropping down from each data point to the X-Axis.
Can anyone help? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem using the LineAnnotation object:

```
int index = 1;
foreach (DataPoint _point in series1.Points)
{
    LineAnnotation annotation = new LineAnnotation();
    annotation.LineColor = Color.Black;
    annotation.LineWidth = 4;
    annotation.LineDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.Dot;
    annotation.AxisX = chartArea1.AxisX;
    annotation.AxisY = chartArea1.AxisY;
    annotation.AnchorX = index;
    annotation.AnchorY = 0;
    annotation.Height = _point.YValues[0];
    annotation.Width = 0;
    annotation.IsSizeAlwaysRelative = false;
    annotation.ClipToChartArea = "ChartArea1";

    chart1.Annotations.Add(annotation);
    index++;
}
```

Funnily enough, the above code behaved strangely when I anchored the annotation to the data point itself, drawing some lines up and some lines down even though all my points are in the same quadrant. After a lot of playing around, I managed to solve the problem by anchoring the annotation to the appropriate "dropped" point on the X-axis.